# Restart JMSItemReader job when messages comes on queue in spring batch

Tags: java, spring, jms, spring-batch

I am using `JmsItemReader` with `JmsTemplate`. `JmsTemplate` is configured with timeout of 10 second so if message doesn't come in 10 second it would give timeout and job get completed.

Now the situation is i want to restart `JmsItemReader` Job whenever there is message on queue and a job is not already running. Can we get some kind of notification for this ?

any help would be really appreciated

Comment: If your goal is to launch a job per message your approach is flawed.

Comment: it should not be per message. it should be like once a new message arrived and job is not running. I know we can do this using Scheduler kind of thing but i am looking some elegant solution provided by spring batch

Comment: And what is wrong with scheduling? Scheduling and batch processing are different things...

Comment: Does it provide poling interval kind of feature or we only need to use spring integration for that.

Comment: Spring Batch does the polling (that is what the `JmsItemReader` is doing). If you want to start a job as soon as a message is available you might want to use Spring Integration but what is wrong with starting with simple scheduling a job each 5 minutes... (It is a start and you can always rewrite / move to more complex solutions).